# Regular expression for splitting a string in Flex/Action Script

Tags: regex, string, actionscript-3, apache-flex, parsing

I have an array of Strings which I want to parse and create an ArrayCollection of Objects.

The Strings will be of the form "[1][2][3][4][5]". Where each number represents the following

1. A name which contain any number of spaces and special characters
2. Any number of spaces
3. A number
4. A single space
5. A string "GB" always

Sample strings are:

- StackOverflow          500 GB
- Stack Over  flow       100 GB
- Stack!@#$%%^&*_ Flow    50 GB

I want to have a regular expression through which I can match the part [1] and [3](ex. StackOverflow and 500) and create objects with these fields.

Comment: It would help if you'd post what you've tried, so anyone who answers doesn't repeat what you already know.

Comment: Also; you haven't added any details on how your sample strings would turn into objects. Should they be generic objects?  Or a special custom object type you've created elsewhere?  Why do you need objects as opposed to an Array of strings?  My intuition at this point is you are going down a road that is going to cause more problems it solves; when an alternate solution will give you what you need easier.

Comment: I'm trying to parse an XML result of a shell command command which I wrote...
A sample output would be like
<result>
preet!@pr{`~#p.$p",.'pree}^_&*()_;+:-|  238 GB
TnG  Datastore2                          238 GB
TnG  Datastore_  VMFS3                     239 GB
<\result>

After this I'm splitting it on "\n" and creating an array of Strings. 

I'm using an ArrayCollection of Objects so as to provide it as the source to a Datagrid's dataprovider.

Comment: @user909458 If it's an xml, I think it'd be easier with an xml parser...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the [split](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#split%28%29) method to turn this into an array.  If you can control the delimiter and make it a single character; I strongly recommend it.  for example, something like this:

```
var myString :String = "1|2|3|4|5";
var myAray :Array = myString.split('|');
```

However, if you have no control over the string delimiter you can use a regular expression.  conceptually something like this:

```
var myString :String = "[1][2][3][4][5]";
var regEx : RegExp = new RegExp([\[]|[\]]|[\[\]]);
var myAray :Array = myString.split(regEx);
```

You should assume my regular expression is imperfect; but more info on creating them [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e91.html).
You may get empty array item at the beginning and end since your string starts and ends with a delimiter.

Comment: My String wouldn't be having the Square braces.
I added them in the question to differentiate the different parts of the string.

Comment: You have a very confusing question then; you may try to be more specific.  If you're getting XML (and not a string) then I'd use Flash's built in e4x functionality for parsing XML.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Flex/Action Script but can suggest general regex.

```
(.*)(\s+)(\d+)(\s)(GB)
```

Create objects with content captured in `\1` and `\3`

Here, each pair of parenthesis captures `[1]` to `[5]` contents, mentioned in the question, into `\1` to `\5` respectively.

Check this in action:
http://regex101.com/r/xF4qS8